# Aggregating Boolean Data in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Is there an accepted/better method to aggregate boolean data in an Access query?

I have two related tables, the first table contains a grouped summary of the data from the second. One of the fields in the second table is a boolean yes/no flag indicating that the row requires 'attention'.

I was planning on essentially performing an OR across the rows of the second table and storing the result in the first table to indicate that 'at least one' of the associated rows from table 2 needs 'attention'.

I see Access stores False as a 0 and True as a -1 and so have just used a SUM/GROUP BY and seem to have achieved the result I was aiming for. Each True value (-1) SUMs and gives me a negative number which Access seems happy to interpret as a True. However I notice that there doesn't seem to be any way to perform an AND operation (multiplication?) which made me think this method I'm using is a bit of a hack and may have some unintended consequences.

Comment: Example of your SQL code please?

Comment: You can add a logical expression `MyAnd: [fieldA] AND [fieldB]` to a query which can then be summarized as you do with a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just using `Sum(-MyFlag)`and compare that to `Count(*)` ? You can then test that both figures are equal.

Comment: This would effectively give you an **AND** wouldn't it?  `Sum(-MyFlag) = Count(*)` **AND**  `Sum(-MyFlag) > 0` **OR**

Comment: Is there any danger here of resulting in some sort of overflow? I think I'm a little confused as to what sort of datatype you'd end up with after summing a boolean value. For example does it 'auto-cast' the result to an integer or long?

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that Access databases store Yes/No values internally as -1 and 0 respectively, it is considered good practice to handle columns using the appropriate methods for their actual type and not rely on "shortcuts" based on their underlying internal values. For example, it is better to use the `DateAdd()` and `DateDiff()` functions rather than doing things like `[Date1]+30` or `[Date2]-[Date1]`.

So, for boolean values I would suggest using `Sum(IIf([NeedsAttention]=True,1,0))` to count the number of rows where [NeedsAttention]=True.

Comment: Why? I do not see that understanding the value of a field and using it should be bad practice.

Comment: @Remou At least two reasons: **(1)** The understanding must be complete. Booleans are fairly straightforward, but messing with Date/Time `Double` values can get *really* complicated (ref: [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/16/53013.aspx)). **(2)** Things might change. What if some day `True` became 1? or some other non-zero value? Writing to the underlying storage is a bit like the bad-old-days of code that bypassed the OS and directly manipulated hardware. It works fine until something (possibly something *very* subtle) changes.

Comment: If you are working with SQL Server back-end, you are usually better off using smallint than boolean, so true is 1, but sum(1) and sum(-1) will always be <> sum(0). Access comes in two parts Jet/ACE and RAD. If you are using Jet/ACE understanding the underlying data is essential.

Comment: @Remou I can appreciate the argument about having an understanding of the underlying storage. In my case there is a fairly high likelihood that I will be ultimately shifting this DB to an SQL backend. Typically I'd prefer trying to write the most 'general' code for my SQL (within my abilities) so I don't have to re-write all my code if I migrate to another platform. There's something about the IIF() that appeals to me in that it's explicitly converting a boolean value to a number. Although that could just be paranoia on my part.